# .Net Core Entity Framework Can't add http put method

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, .net-core

Prject.csproj, provides the following lines:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.6.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.6.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="CloudinaryDotNet" Version="1.8.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="3.1.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1"/>
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
```

I'm using this model:

```
namespace Amaz.API.Models
{
    public class Cosa
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public int UserId {get; set;}
        public string descripcion {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Which is designed this way in the DataContext.cs as far as EntityFramework is used:

```
using Amaz.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Amaz.API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>,
    UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}

        public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Familiar> Familiars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Situation> Situations { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Cosa> Cosas { get; set; }


          protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
         {
             base.OnModelCreating(builder);

             builder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole =>
             {
                 userRole.HasKey(ur => new {ur.UserId, ur.RoleId});

                 userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                    .IsRequired();

                 userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();   
             });

             builder.Entity<Like>()
                 .HasKey(k => new {k.LikerId, k.LikeeId});

              builder.Entity<Like>()
                 .HasOne(u => u.Likee)
                 .WithMany(u => u.Likers)
                 .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikeeId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

              builder.Entity<Like>()
                 .HasOne(u => u.Liker)
                 .WithMany(u => u.Likees)
                 .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikerId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

             builder.Entity<Message>()
                 .HasOne(u => u.Sender)
                 .WithMany(m => m.MessagesSent)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

              builder.Entity<Message>()
                 .HasOne(u => u.Recipient)
                 .WithMany(m => m.MessagesReceived)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
               
              builder.Entity<Photo>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsApproved);

              builder.Entity<Familiar>() 
                 .HasOne(u => u.Users)
                 .WithMany(m => m.Familiars)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 
                         
              builder.Entity<Situation>(); 

              builder.Entity<Cosa>();
                
         }
    }
}
```

And the controller is:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using AutoMapper;
    using CloudinaryDotNet;
    using CloudinaryDotNet.Actions;
    using Amaz.API.Data;
    using Amaz.API.Dtos;
    using Amaz.API.Helpers;
    using Amaz.API.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
    
    namespace Amaz.API.Controllers
    {
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class CosaController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly IVVRepository _repo;
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;
            public CosaController(IVVRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
            {
               
                _mapper = mapper;
                _repo = repo;
    
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> PutCosa(CosaDto CosaDto)
            {
                var CosaToCreate = _mapper.Map<Cosa>(CosaDto);
                _repo.Add(CosaToCreate);
    
                return NoContent();
            }

            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetCosa (int id)
    
            {
    
                  var cosareturn = await _repo.GetCosa(id);
    
                  if (cosareturn == null)
                     return NotFound();
    
                  return Ok(cosareturn);
            }
    
            [HttpPut("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCosa(int id, CosaDto CosaDto)
            {

    
                var cosa = await _repo.GetCosa(id);
    
                _mapper.Map(CosaDto, cosa);
                return NoContent();
            }
    
            [HttpDelete("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCosa (int id)
    
            {            
                  var CosaFromRepo = await _repo.GetCosa(id);
                  _repo.Delete(CosaFromRepo);
    
                  return NoContent();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the main problem is that it is not possible to add a new register to the database through this "PutCosa" method. As Its tested in Postman:
[image: Postman screen capture here:]

What could be failing here and how to solve it?

Comment: Why is it "not possible"? Your Postman image shows the response is 204 (No Content) which is the value you return? - `return NoContent();`

Comment: You are getting response 204.  See : https://httpstatuses.com/204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF you actually need to Save your changes on the context so that EF will put the changes to the DB. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCosa(CosaDto CosaDto)
        {
            var CosaToCreate = _mapper.Map<Cosa>(CosaDto);
            _repo.Add(CosaToCreate);
            _repo.SaveChanges();
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: Adding a little example code and using the [English docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/saving/basic) would make this a better answer?

Comment: Yes! It works, so easy and and the same time difficult to see. Thanks a lot!